# how to add or condition in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to add or condition in xslt ?

here is my code

http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSP

I want to check a node ("a" in my example ).If it present then get it's value else get value from another node ("b" in my example)

**first case :**

xml

```
<c>
<a>sss</a>
<b>hhhh</b>
</c>
```

**expected out put**

```
 <h1>sss</h1>
```

**second case**

```
<c>

<b>hhhh</b>
</c>
```

**expected output**

```
   <h1>hhhh</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="c[a]/a | c[not(a)]/b"/>
        </h1>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do a union of two expressions, selecting `a` inside `c`if a exists, selecting `b` inside `c` if `a` does not exists.

Comment: Checking `c[a]/a` is redundant, `c/a` would suffice.

Comment: are yu using xslt 2..?

Comment: I am trying to give else condition as hard corded string ""bbb"

Comment: did you get my point I try to set hard coded string instead of `getting value from another node`

Comment: Use `<xsl:if test="expression">` to achieve this: http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSP/2